# How to align, with comma separator and specific decimal points in Python prints

Tags: python, printing

When printing a number in python I would like to

1. Align right (using the align specifier `>`)
2. Align width (using the width specific)
3. Specify the number of decimal places
4. Set a separator between the thousands

I know how do to each of these separately. Let's take the number `1000000.12345` as example.

(1 & 2 & 3) Doing `print(f"1000000.12345:>20.2")` which results in

```
          1000000.12
```

I also know how to only do (1 & 2 & 4). Namely `print(f"{1000000.12345:>20,}")` which results in

```
     1,000,000.12345
```

But what I want is to do the latter but also trim the decimal places, such that I get something like

```
        1,000,000.12
```

How can I do that?

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language - it's `[width][grouping_option]["." precision]` so `20,.2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) this can be done with:

```
print(f"{1000000.12345:>20,.2f}")
```

Works on my machine.